# How do I fix the ORA-12154 error on IIS?

Tags: php, oracle, iis, oracle11g

I know this is an very unusual set, but I need to do this:

I have a php application who needs to connect to Oracle. It was working fine through the php odbc library, but then I needed tho change the server, so the issues begin..

At the SQL Plus application and ODBC Manager tool, it works, but wher I use oci or odbc connection on php, returns the ora-12154 error.

Here's a piece of code:

```
$tnsName = "svr_aplicacao";
try {
  if ($bd->link=oci_connect($usrName, $pwd, $tnsName)) {
    $err = '';
    $bd->result = true;
  } else {
    $err = oci_error();
    $bd->codErro = $err['code'];    
    $bd->msgErro = $err['message'];
    $bd->result = false;
  }
}catch (Exception $e){
  print_r ($e);
}
```

and below there's the tnsnames.ora declaration:

```
svr_aplicacao =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.248)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

I already tried to set TNS_ADMIN environment variable, but then the error changes to "No TNS listener"

Is there any oracle file/folder access that I should apply to IIS or something ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

after one full day trying to solve this, there's a solution:

1 - download the PHP non thread binary and reinstall at C:\PHP folder. It seems that the parentesis in program files (x86) folder was causing the error.

2 - change PHP version on IIS

3 - go to IIS -> PHP Manager -> PHP Setup:

- register new PHP version -> indicating c:\PHP folder
- change PHP version

4 - go to IIS -> PHP Manager -> PHP Extensions
  - re-enable libraries oci8, oci8_11g, ldap and fileinfo

It works for me.
hope it can help someone